# How I fix these problem,, Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52821/4-VBDlY84wk=/

Tags: flutter

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52821/4-VBDlY84wk=/
```

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52821/4-VBDlY84wk=/

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G530H in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52821/4-VBDlY84wk=/
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.